# Best Practices extending entities on Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm interested in recommended best practices when entities customizations are required on Dynamics CRM 2011. Microsoft recommends [to modify built-in entities instead of creating new ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509027.aspx#CustomizationBestPractices), but I'm concerned about forward compatibility in future upgrades, using this approach.

What are recommended best practices:

1. Customize built-in entities
2. Create new independent-system entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want you're doing Lester.  The reason they recommend using a built in entity is that you don't have to create it, define it, create the views, create the form, or anything.  That's all done for you.  If you need to keep track of an individual's address and other personal information, use the contact entity.  Add the fields you need.  Hide the ones you don't.

If you need to do something that isn't really supported by any of the built in entities, by all means, create your own.  Just remember you'll need to define the icons, views, forms, and security for it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are attempting to create.

If you need a contact record then in the large majority of cases you will utilize the contact entity and customize as appropriate. On the other hand, if I needed to do grant management I'm unlikely to just extend an existing entity - instead I'll create the Grant entity and the appropriate related entities as custom entities. Yes, you might be able to reuse some of the existing to accomplish your goals but there is really no good reason to do so, and you run the risk of not being able to use customized built-in entity should you need it for its intended purpose in the future.

So the quick take away is to ask yourself this question: Based on the requirements do I have a natural fit to an existing entity? (i.e., this solution has order management it should fit with the order entity, etc.)

If no, build a custom entity.

If yes, ask yourself the next question: Is the business logic I'm implementing inline with how CRM works OOTB? If yes, use built-in entity and customize. If no, build a custom entity.

Hope that helps - there is no great binary decision. A lot of it is based on preference and experience along with an understanding of how the solution will evolve over time.